# SSL binding IIS7

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate, bindings

I'm not sure I can do what I want to do but here goes...

I have the following 2 websites setup on IIS 7 with the bindings specified

- Production Web Site
  Bindings:

  - http / www.mydomain.com / 80
  - https / www.mydomain.com / 443
- Staging Web Site
  Bindings:

  - http / sub1.mydomain.com / 80
  - https / sub1.mydomain.com / 443

I have a UC (SAN) SSL Certificate which covers all the domains. And I used the * friendly name trick when installing the cert to allow me to specify the bindings for the https.

Problem is when I visit https://sub1.domain.com I am seeing the Production website not the site on the staging.

As you can probably see I am having to use one server to managing a staging/testing site and the actually production site. Not ideal I know.

anyone know if what I'm doing is achievable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are performing the configuration via the IIS management console UI, that will not work. You have to use the *appcmd* command-line utility.

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html

Answer (score 0):

As well you might be able to add second IP to the server and configure the sub1 site to use it.

Comment: thanks, but I'm going to have alot of subdomains (one per client) so I don't really want to have to use different ips per client.